# Umbraco DB log error: Couldn't find any page with the nodeId = 0

Tags: logging, crash, umbraco, deadlock

I have been getting this error in Umbraco, it has caused a crash on the server and the database. I'm not sure what is causing the error as it does not give much information, there is no node ID, each time a page is accessed on the server these lines are written over and over in the **UmbracoLog** table:

```
Couldn't find any page with the nodeId = 0. 
This is most likely caused by the page isn't published!  Parameter name: nodeId
```

Does anyone have any idea as to what is causing this? I am using Umbraco v 4.7.1.1

Comment: I started getting the same problem today. No clue as to what is generating the entires.

Comment: Does the back office work OK?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?  I've been seeing the same for several months.  Umbraco 4.7.1.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried republishing all your site? I got the same error and that fixed it.